# How do I include an absolute path to a C# assembly DLL to reference in my C# class library?

Tags: c#

I am making an XLL using C# with ExcelDNA, and all works fine so far apart from one thing - I have to call a 3rd-party DLL (also developed in .NET in C#) and that I am certain is installed (with admin privileges) to a fixed absolute path on all user machines.

When I add a reference to the DLL to my csproj file (by Browsing to the DLL on my machine), it all seems to work (when I add the required 'using' statement), except that my csproj file adds a **relative** path to the HintPath field for the reference.

How do I add the DLL as a reference that will always be looked for in an absolute location?

The relevant section of my csproj file looks like (when it seems to work):

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="SIMExporterEbmlImport">
    <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\ProgramData\EB Bridging Tools\SimExporter\SIMExporterEbmlImport.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And then I can do this in my actual code:

```cs
using SIMExporterEbmlImport;
[...]
SIMExporterEbmlImport.MyClass obj = new SIMExporterEbmlImport.MyClass();
```

How do I go about ensuring:

1. An absolute path is used (to the reference DLL) at runtime by whatever machine is running my XLL.
2. A local copy is not made of the DLL, but it actually uses the pre-existing copy on each user's machine (with error handling, of course, to catch when it does not exist!).

You can probably tell by the question that I am not a professional C# developer, but trying to understand just enough to make this work. But as a consequence, if there is a simpler/more elegant solution to this issue, by all means please suggest it.

Comment: (1) The location found at build time isn't supposed to influence the path searched at runtime.   (2) If the automatic search fails at runtime, you can handle the [`AssemblyResolve` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?view=net-7.0) and use the path of your choice

Comment: @Sinatr: That duplicate seems to be a false friend, because it's about using absolute paths for build time and this one is about using absolute paths at runtime.

Comment: a.) if its just an Assembly why not deploy it with your app? b.) If its needs somehow be installed separately is it because of additional dependencies this assembly has?

Comment: You might add a [probing path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element) to you app.config to also look in other specified diectories to look for assemblies

Comment: @Ralf - yes I am required to use a pre-existing instance of the target DLL, that has been registered with RegAsm (but using \codebase). How do I include a reference to that specific assembly in my csproj file, rather than a local copy?

Comment: @Ralf, I am unsure what file to put the probing path into to give it a go - some of the project files are autogenerated/hidden from me by ExcelDNA, so that may be confusing things. But I am not sure even in general terms where that XML code goes!

Comment: RegAsm sounds like its not just a simple Assembly but a COM Component.

Comment: OK, so what is the 'correct' way to access that COM Component at runtime from my class library? I tried using Assembly.Load with absolute path and without a path and it fails every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very helpful (much more C-literate) colleague helped me find an answer, without my previous hacky workaround:

1. Create an event handler for the ResolveEventHandler and ensure it is loaded before any calls to methods that need to use classes from the missing assembly:

```cs
// This field goes in one of my classes:
public static bool isAssemblyResolveRegistered = false;

// This code goes just before my method that needs to use the class in my assembly that
// I know won't be preloaded, but needs loading from a fixed location:
if (!isAssemblyResolveRegistered)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(AssemblyResolve);
    isAssemblyResolveRegistered = true;
}
```

2. Use the following event handler code:

```cs
private static Assembly AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{ // This is an event handler for catching missing assemblies at runtime - designed to find and load the SIMExporterEbmlImport assembly and its dependencies
    
    // Assume a fixed path for where the assembly is located (can update this later to look in multiple versions if needed)
    // Should also add a switch block to only look for expected dependencies in this location,
    // and throw a helpful error if some unexpected dependency is missing.
    string dependentAssemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name;
    string dependentAssemblyLocation = "C:\\ProgramData\\EB Bridging Tools\\SimExporter\\" + dependentAssemblyName + ".dll";


    // Try to load (will end up back here if lower dependencies are not met)
    try
    {
        return Assembly.LoadFile(dependentAssemblyLocation);
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

That means that I always explicitly handle unloaded dependencies at runtime, and can even supply multiple search paths if I ever need to (for different, but equally compatible, versions, for example).

My only residual issue (may open a separate question for this) is how to elegantly abort all execution with a user dialog if the DLLs are simply not present on the runtime machine.